# GoogleSignIn Authentication in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile

I'm confused related to the `GoogleSignIn Logout` first I've managed to `SignIn` my google account, the problem is when I logout my google account, and SignIn again the previous account that you login before it didn't ask the password like the image below when I click one of user account it will go to my home screen directly instead asking password for that google account since I've already logout the account in my app.

[image]

**This is my logout function** I tried the code below it works in some other way but my concern is since I've already logout the account it should not directly go to `homepage` when `SignIn` again ask password to the user or remove user when logout? What is the best way should I do, do I correcly implement it?

```
   const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
   logout: async () => {
      try {
        await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess();
        await GoogleSignin.signOut();
        setUser({ user: null });
        await auth().signOut();
        
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    },
```

**GoogleSign function**

```
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        googleLogin: async () => {
          try {
            // Get the users ID token
            const Token  = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
            const {idToken} =  Token;
            
            // Create a Google credential with the token
            const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
        
          
            // Sign-in the user with the credential
            await auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential)            
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Something went wrong with sign up: ', error);
            });
          } catch(error) {
            console.log({error});
          }
        },
      }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer:
Your code is completely fine!

Long Answer:
This is completely normal behaviour and is intended to be. If you want to Sign Out completely you would have to go into the settings of the corresponding google account and sign out from that device.
(Manage Google Account => Security => My Devices => Logout)

Comment: What if you have your app installed to your phone and you login your account then you logout and then there's someone want to login their account to your phone and then they  accidentally used your google account since it didn't ask password, do you have any idea to prevent this?

Comment: This is not part of your original question but you would have to implement a second layer of security. A lot of banking and trading apps have this applied, most of the time you can login with face id or via a 4 number pin.

Comment: Okay I got it last one more question you said that in order to remove or signout completely the google account you should go to the settings, is there any other option or code just to remove automatically the google account instead removing it manually?

Comment: I don't know if thats possible

Answer (score 0):

try removing the await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess();
this worked for me after removing revoke access

```
useEffect(() => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId:
        'nmgqmhuak76u9evobvkdm8oil764a9e3.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    });
  }, []);

const signInWithGoogleAsync = async () => {
    try {
      const {idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
      const user_sign_in = auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
      user_sign_in
        .then(user => {
          console.log(user);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          if (error.code === 'auth/network-request-failed') {
            ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
              'A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.]',
              ToastAndroid.SHORT,
              ToastAndroid.CENTER,
            );
          }
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

const logout = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.signOut();
      await auth().signOut();
      ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
        'Signing Off',
        ToastAndroid.SHORT,
        ToastAndroid.CENTER,
      );
      navigation.replace('login');
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

};

Comment: plz try this one it works for me. - @shainnah jane